# Adding a Contents folder in a resource bundle breaks ability to get pathForResource:

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle

I have a bundle, say "Sample.bundle". I get the path for a html resource by using

```
NSBundle *sampleBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Sample" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
NSString *path = [sampleBundle pathForResource:@"Terms" ofType:@"html"];
```

But if I add a Contents folder, I couldn't get the resource path by the same method (This happens irrespective of whether the folder contains an Info.plist, which I suspected was the issue at first). Can someone point the issue here? Cannot add images, sorry.

Comment: What is the path of the resource you want to find? `Contents/Terms.html`? Have you tried `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:]`?

Comment: @Mats Its just at the root of the bundle. i.e. Sample.bundle/Terms.html

Comment: After some struggle, I have a partial resolution to the issue. If one needs to add a bundle with a Contents folder at the root of the bundle, any resources that should go inside the bundle MUST be placed inside 

    "$(BundleRoot)/Contents/Resources/"
Any resources outside this directory cannot be accessed by me. If you do not have a Contents folder in the root of the bundle, you could place your resources anywhere. I do not know the reason why this happens, maybe, more experienced members can explain.

Comment: It is somewhat described in [Anatomy of a Loadable Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW32).